# Spinner Intent Activity Change

Tags: android

I've been trying to get my spinner logic to change activities on selection change, but the code below for some reason isn't changing.  Log.d returns the correct selection, so I know the itemSelect is triggering, but not sure why intent is not changing.

```
public class ListOwnersActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener, OnClickListener {


Spinner spinner;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_cars);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    ArrayAdapter adapter= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.domain,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    addListener();


}
public void addListener() {

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                                       int position, long row_id) {
                if (arg0.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals("OwnersList")) {
                    Log.d("position", "position: " + position);
                    Intent y = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListOwnersActivity.class);
                    startActivity(y);
                }

                if (arg0.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals("CarList")) {
                    Log.d("position", "position: " + position);
                    Intent x = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListCarsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(x);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried debugging??

Comment: Remove this `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);` Can you post the activity complete

Comment: Please put complete code of your activity class.

Comment: i guess you are having the listener twice. Your activity implementing the interface and you have a annonymous inner class. Post your whole activity code

Comment: I updated my code with the Activity class.  Still nothing.  I'm getting Log.d to respond with itemSelection values, but the activity is still not changing. Also, if I remove spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);, the program seems to fall into an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by 'intent is not changing'. Can you try changing the second if with else if.

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in your onItemSelected method it will work perfectly.

```
String temp = String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());
    if(temp.contentEquals("OwnersList"))
    {
                        Log.d("position", "position: " + position);
                        Intent y = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListOwnersActivity.class);
                        startActivity(y);
                    }
    if(temp.contentEquals("CarList"))
    {
                        Log.d("position", "position: " + position);
                        Intent x = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListCarsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(x);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please remove **spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);** line from **onCreate()** ?

Btw you did code of onItemSelectedListener() two times.

1) By basic interface **spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)**

2) You have added **addListener()** method it also contains **setOnItemSelectedListener**.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I removed it from my code. Now only setOnItemSelectedListener code is directly in my onCreate()

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  The activity is not changing.  And in addition when my .xml loads and the spinner loads the page falls into an endless loop.